# can't get selenium to give me gpu prices

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to web Scraping and can't get the prices i have found them in the terminal but the list appears empty despite this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


url = "https://www.kuantokusta.pt/p/6894201/msi-geforce-rtx-3080-ventus-3x-plus-oc-lhr-10gb-gddr6"

driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

doc = BeautifulSoup(html , "html.parser")
print(doc.prettify())
prices = doc.find_all(text="EUR")
print(prices)
```

Comment: What is your question? What does "found them in the terminal" mean?

Comment: I print the html and found the prices in the html but the last part the find_all says there are no text "EUR" which i know is not true because i found them in the html file

Comment: So now your question is "why does find_all not find what I am telling it to find"? Maybe you could prepare a [mre] of an HTML document which contains what you want to extract with `find_all` but it doesn't return it.

Comment: a cookie appears when running this code.  can you confirm that you bypass the cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS class `.prices` and especially `.old-price` and `.new-price`.

So, you could use them as follow:

```py
prices = doc.select('.prices')
```

or

```py
prices = doc.select('.old-price')
```

or

```py
prices = doc.select('.new-price')
```